# Using MAF with Prism or CAL

Tags: c#, add-in, prism, maf

I am in processes of migrating my CAB application to Prism. And facing a specific request of having all the modules hosted in the shell be in different Appdomain. Was thinking of using MAF to achive this... Can any one give me some heads up on how to go about it..

Thanks in advance
Vikram

Answer (score 4):

I've done a [few posts](http://kentb.blogspot.com/search/label/MAF) on MAF (though not specifically regarding Prism) that may be of help. You're in for a world of pain, I'm afraid.

Comment: Kent ur posts are very helpful.. But i am looking for how to incorporate MAF with Prism..